# Understanding COUNT() as `count`

Tags: php, mysql, authentication, count

I'm currently learning how to build a site in PHP MySQL.  However, I seem to fail to understand `COUNT() as count` and wouldn't mind some further explanation.

I get the principles of `COUNT`, `0 || 1`, and how it returns all the values that pertain to that query.

But, don't see how COUNT as count works.  Anyhow, this is how the code I'm writing goes - so we have a working example - and where I first became perplexed.

```
"SELECT COUNT(id) as count, id
 FROM user
 WHERE email='$email' AND password='".md5$password."'"
```

Comment: Just a side note: take care that you escape those variables you inject into the query. It looks like your code is wide open to 'sql injections'. Best is to use a solution like PDO instead of trying to reinvent an escaping strategy.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will real_escape the email in a function, the md5 will be fine without - right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is what is called alias which is sometimes used to show a more appealing column header to users or the calling code

```
SELECT COUNT(`id`) as `count`....
```

will print

```
count
--------
5
```

The alias standing as the column header instead of any arbitrary string: [See the SQLFiddle to see the difference](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aa1c0/1)

From the fiddle you can see that the header column looks somehow e.g.

```
count(*)
--------
5
```

Answer (score 2):

With [`Count()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html) you can count the returning rows of a result set. The also the official MySQL documentation about [count](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/counting-rows.html):

> Databases are often used to answer the question, “How often does a certain type of data occur in a table?” For example, you might want to know how many pets you have, or how many pets each owner has, or you might want to perform various kinds of census operations on your animals.
>
> Counting the total number of animals you have is the same question as “How many rows are in the pet table?” because there is one record per pet. COUNT(*) counts the number of rows, so the query to count your animals looks like this:
>
> `SELECT COUNT(*) FROM pet;`

The part with `AS count` means that this colum will get a name which you can use e.g. in PHP. See also this explenation on [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_alias.asp):

> You can give a table or a column another name by using an alias. This can be a good thing to do if you have very long or complex table names or column names.
>
> An alias name could be anything, but usually it is short.

Comment: I think the question is refering to the `as count` part, too. Which means you can reference the result as `count` !?

Comment: I added a line about that. However I didn't find a better explanation on the official site. I'll keep looking for that.

Answer (score 1):

`as count` is just an alias. You can use `as` for any field or method selected. it means you change the name of the column being returned in your dataset.

```
SELECT `field` as another_name
```

So:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as `count`
```

Just renames the column from `COUNT(*)` to `count` making it easier to work with whereever you are maniuplating your result set.

It also makes for easier access within your current query. Many would do the following with large table names:

```
SELECT * FROM `table_with_ridiculous_name` as twrn WHERE twrn.id = 1
```

Comment: @edlee no worries :) you can also do the following for many SQL implementations -- however it generally confuses people even more than the `as` keyword. `SELECT field fieldalias` basically missing out the `as` keyword altogether.

Answer (score 0):

If you ran this sql:

```
SELECT COUNT(id), id ....
```

You would get (after doing a *_fetch_assoc) `$row['numberofrecordshere']` which would be very hard to echo (or use in a comparison) unless you knew how many records there would be (which would defeat the purpose of this result, anyway)

Returning it as count allows you to get to it in the resulting array by using `$row['count']`